# Django select only rows with duplicate field values

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

suppose we have a model in django defined as follows:

```
class Literal:
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

Name field is not unique, and thus can have duplicate values. I need to accomplish the following task:
Select all rows from the model that have **at least one duplicate value** of the `name` field.

I know how to do it using plain SQL (may be not the best solution):

```
select * from literal where name IN (
    select name from literal group by name having count((name)) > 1
);
```

So, is it possible to select this using django ORM? Or better SQL solution?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Literal.objects.values('name')
               .annotate(Count('id')) 
               .order_by()
               .filter(id__count__gt=1)
```

This is as close as you can get with Django. The problem is that this will return a `ValuesQuerySet` with only `name` and `count`. However, you can then use this to construct a regular `QuerySet` by feeding it back into another query:

```
dupes = Literal.objects.values('name')
                       .annotate(Count('id'))
                       .order_by()
                       .filter(id__count__gt=1)
Literal.objects.filter(name__in=[item['name'] for item in dupes])
```

Comment: Probably you have meant ``Literal.objects.values('name').annotate(name_count=Count('name')).filter(name_count__gt=1)``?

Comment: Original query gives ``Cannot resolve keyword 'id_count' into field``

Comment: Sorry, yes. Had some issues with the code, as I was working from memory. Current version of my answer works.

Comment: Thanks for updated answer, I think I will stick with this solution, you can even do it without list comprehension by using ``values_list('name', flat=True)``

Comment: Right. Nice. I always forget about `flat=True` ;).

Comment: `FieldError: Join on field 'id' not permitted. Did you misspell 'count' for the lookup type?`

Comment: Django previously had a bug on this (might have been fixed in recent versions) where if you don't specify a fieldname for the `Count` annotation to saved as, it defaults to `[field]__count`. However, that double-underscore syntax is also how Django interprets you wanting to do a join. So, essentially when you try to filter on that, Django thinks you're trying to do a join with `count` which obviously doesn't exist. The fix is to specify a name for your annotation result, i.e. `annotate(mycount=Count('id'))` and then filter on `mycount` instead.

Comment: if you add another call to `values('name')` after your call to annotate, you can remove the list comprehension and say `Literal.objects.filter(name__in=dupes)` which will allow this to all be executed in a single query.

Comment: I tried it. It works great except for duplicates where the values are None or blank string. For those, you'd get wrong numbers.

Comment: Can it be modified to case insensitive ? case insensitive names ?

Comment: This works for me for finding all duplicated items. Is there a way to skip the first duplicated while I want to keep one of them?

Comment: order_by is not needed

Answer (score 66):

This was rejected as an edit. So here it is as a *better* answer

```
dups = (
    Literal.objects.values('name')
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))
    .values('name')
    .order_by()
    .filter(count__gt=1)
)
```

This will return a `ValuesQuerySet` with all of the duplicate names. However, you can then use this to construct a regular `QuerySet` by feeding it back into another query. The django ORM is smart enough to combine these into a single query:

```
Literal.objects.filter(name__in=dups)
```

The extra call to `.values('name')` after the annotate call looks a little strange. Without this, the subquery fails. The extra values tricks the ORM into only selecting the name column for the subquery.

Comment: Nice trick, unfortunately this will only work if just one value is used (eg. if both 'name' and 'phone' where used, the last part wouldn't work).

Comment: What is the `.order_by()` for?

Comment: @stefanfoulis It clears out any existing ordering. If you have a model-set ordering, this becomes part of the SQL `GROUP BY` clause, and that breaks things. Found that out when playing with Subquery (in which you do very similar grouping via `.values()`)

Answer (score 12):

try using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation)

```
Literal.objects.values('name').annotate(name_count=Count('name')).exclude(name_count=1)
```

Comment: Ok, that gives the corrent list of names, but is it possible to selects ids and other fields at the same time?

Comment: @dragoon - no but Chris Pratt has covered the alternative in his answer.

Answer (score 7):

In case you use PostgreSQL, you can do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import Func, Value

duplicate_ids = (Literal.objects.values('name')
                 .annotate(ids=ArrayAgg('id'))
                 .annotate(c=Func('ids', Value(1), function='array_length'))
                 .filter(c__gt=1)
                 .annotate(ids=Func('ids', function='unnest'))
                 .values_list('ids', flat=True))
```

It results in this rather simple SQL query:

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY_AGG("app_literal"."id")) AS "ids"
FROM "app_literal"
GROUP BY "app_literal"."name"
HAVING array_length(ARRAY_AGG("app_literal"."id"), 1) > 1
```

Comment: I tried this but python code gave me an error: `FieldError: Expression contains mixed types: ArrayField, IntegerField. You must set output_field.`. However, SQL query works as  expected (Django 3.2)

Comment: Works great (Django 2.2). Also, you don't need the `array_length` annotation, and can instead filter by `ids__len` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#len

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so for some reason none of the above worked for, it always returned `<MultilingualQuerySet []>`. I use the following, much easier to understand but not so elegant solution:

```
dupes = []
uniques = []

dupes_query = MyModel.objects.values_list('field', flat=True)

for dupe in set(dupes_query):
    if not dupe in uniques:
        uniques.append(dupe)
    else:
        dupes.append(dupe)

print(set(dupes))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to result only names list but not objects, you can use the following query

```
repeated_names = Literal.objects.values('name').annotate(Count('id')).order_by().filter(id__count__gt=1).values_list('name', flat='true')
```