# Django select rows with duplicate field values for specific foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

[again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values) I would like to search for duplicates in my models, but now slightly different case.

Here are my models:

```
class Concept(models.Model):
    main_name = models.ForeignKey(Literal)
    ...
class Literal(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(...)
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept)
    ...
```

And now the task I'm trying to achieve:
Select all literals that are **NOT** main_names, that have the **same name** for the **same concept**.

For example if I have literals:

```
[{id:1, name:'test', concept:1}, {id:2, name:'test', concept:1}]
```

and concepts:

```
[{id:1, main_name:1}]
```

Then in result I should get literal with the ID=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as though you want to execute a SQL query something like this:

```
SELECT l1.* FROM myapp_literal AS l1,
                 myapp_literal AS l2
WHERE l1.id <> l2.id
  AND l1.name = l2.name
  AND l1.concept = l2.concept
  AND l1.id NOT IN (SELECT main_name FROM myapp_concept)
GROUP BY l1.id
```

Well, in cases where the query is too complex to easily express in Django's query language, you can [always ask Django to do a raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/)—and this may be one of those cases.

Comment: Yes, I think I gives exactly what I want, except that you need to specify l1.id instead of l1.*, otherwise it will be `column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: could you also tell me what should I write do delete everything selected from l1?

Comment: I guess I'm too used to MySQL, which [allows non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` part of `GROUP BY` queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). You're quite right to point out that in most databases this won't be allowed.

Comment: To delete the records matching a query, you can [use Django's `delete` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects) on the query. Something like `Literal.objects.raw('SELECT ...').delete()` But take care—the query I wrote selects *all* records with duplicates—you probably want to delete *all but one* of each matching set.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want:

1. All Literal objects that are not ForeignKey'd to Concept.
2. From that set, select those where the name and the concept is the same.

If so, I think this should work:

For the first part:

```
q = Literal.objects.exclude(pk__in=Concept.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

EDIT:

Based on excellent feedback from Jan, I think for #2 you would need to use [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.extra).

Comment: It should be `values_list` and I think your second part doesn't do anything. Do you mean `q.filter(name=F('concept__main_name__name'))`? I'm not sure if this is optimal in performance though.

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance part to be honest; but I think the F expression is correct as per my understanding of the docs.

Thanks for the `values_list`, edited.

Comment: Does it not just test whether the literal's name equals its own name (same for concept), which is of course true for all literals?

Comment: OK. I posted a possible solution in my comment and think that it *does* actually work, without using raw SQL but foreign-key lookups.

Comment: Yep, I know have to select all not main literals, this is fairly simple, my insterest was how to perform the whole task. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @JanPöschko, in the query in your comment you will get dulicates throughout the whole table, but I need only duplicates for the same concept.