# Find duplicate entries in database for specific fields

Tags: django

I have model having fields as name, school, email, address etc.

I want to find out the rows for which there is same entry for `name` and `school` field ?

```
eg:
name school email 
abc     mps    abc@gmail.com
abc     mps    abc@gmail.com
xyz     vps    xyz@gmail.com
abc     mps    abc@gmail.com
poi     vps    poi@gmail.com
jkl     vps    jkl@gmail.com
```

like for `name` abc and `school` mps ther are 3 entries and for xyz and vps there are 2 entries 
I can nested `for` loop and iterative manner to check the name and school fields against all the rows in the table. That would be performance hit (n*n)

Is there any other way to find out ?

Comment: do you have the name and school you are looking for or do you want to get all counts name/school combinations?

Comment: I think it's solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values

Basically you group by name or school and then check if count > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) will serve the purpose.
The following will solve your problem

```
model_name.objects.values_list('name').distinct()
```

If you want dictionary then you have to do this

```
model_name.objects.values('name').distinct()
```

Hope that solves you issue!!

Comment: @FrEaKmAn "Returns a new QuerySet that uses SELECT DISTINCT in its SQL query. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results." thats what the official docs say when you goto the link that i have mentioned

Comment: but how does this solve the question 

I want to find out the rows for which there is same entry for name and school field ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you, you just want to get the results wich has the **SAME** name and school, or just want to get **ONE** result for name and school ?

This sentence will return **ALL** schools with name 'abc' and school 'mps'

`result_list = model.objects.filter(name='abc').filter(school='mps')`

---

If you're trying to get only **ONE** result per name and school, you have to use distinct() 
like:

`result_list = model.objects.filter(name='abc').filter(school='mps').distinct()` `

---