# Django find duplicates with queryset and regex

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django, is it possible to find duplicates with queryset and regex?

[Django select only rows with duplicate field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values)
shows without using a regex:

```
self.values('Website').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by().filter(count__gt=1)
```

I have a model:

```
class company(models.Model):
   Website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True )
```

I want to find duplicates with regex

For example.

```
Company.objects.create(Website='http://example.com')
Company.objects.create(Website='http://www.example.com')
```

Both of these are the same website.  I'd like to use a regex so that it will return return these companies as duplicates.

I know there is filters like  that use regex.  I'm not sure how to update this to use a regex:

```
self.values('Website').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by().filter(count__gt=1)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
Website__iregex='http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
```

**Update**
There was some confusion so I'll give an example.

Here is what my db looks like

```
Company.objects.create(Website='http://example.com')
Company.objects.create(Website='http://www.example.com')
Company.objects.create(Website='http://example.org', Name='a')
Company.objects.create(Website='http://example.org', Name='b')
```

When I call

```
Company.objects.all().values('Website').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by().filter(count__gt=1)
```

It returns:

1. http://example.org (from name=a) and http://example.org (from name=b)

This is missing that example.com and www.example.com are the same website.

I want to use a regex so that I can tell django that example.com and www.example.com are the same websites.

I want to modify:

```
Company.objects.all().values('Website').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by().filter(count__gt=1)
```

so that it returns the duplicates:

1. http://example.org (from name=a) and http://example.org (from name=b)
2. example.com www.example.com

Comment: Does this `.annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by().filter(count__gt=1)` work at all???

Answer (score 1):

Use [__icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#icontains):

```
Company.objects.filter(Website__icontains='example.com')
```

Which will produce:

```
`ILIKE %'example.com'%.
```

It will thus return the following records if exists in the Company table:

```
 http://example.com, http://www.example.com
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to find the duplicates.  In my example I want a way to find the duplicates where Django will realize "example.com" and "www.example.com" is the same website.

Comment: and with the above queryset it will

Comment: I want to run a queryset that finds the duplicate websites.  Your code assumes I know the duplicate urls.  Also it creates an object which  I assume is a typo.  I want to modify this expression so that it will realize www and non-www is the same website: values('Website').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by().filter(count__gt=1)

Comment: Updated my answer. And I was a bit fast copying there and did not see your first queryset was a create.

Comment: There is some confusing about what I want.  I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar DB structure on some project - i store urls of some entities. To find duplicates i also store the 'domain' of url.

So regarding your examples the DB structure would be:

```
id |           url          | domain
-----------------------------------------
1  | http://www.example.com | example.com
2  | http://example.com     | example.com
```

It's easy then to find duplicates or find urls/entities related to particular domain.

You may think that using such an approach is an overkill to detect duplicates.

But your approach has 2 big drawbacks:

1) it's impossible to write correct regexp that will match domains variations

Matching "www.example.com" and "example.com" is easy. How about "example.co.uk" and "www.example.co.uk" or maybe "www.старт.рф" and "старт.рф" ? Those are all valid domain names.

2) you are shooting your leg in the long run - writing complex regexps on ever growing DB tables *will* kill your performance.

p.s. - i use "tldextract" lib to get domain of urls.