# Django Count rows with duplicate values

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on counting rows with duplicate values in a django Model and running into a little hitch.
I have looked at this question [Django Select Rows with duplicate Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values/8989348)

and the solution is perfect. But my question is, What if I want to **Count the rows and group them according to: Name of the duplicated row, and how many times it has been duplicated,** instead of just displaying the name of the repeated rows.

**my code so far:**

**`views.py`**

```
dupes = Application.objects.values('school_name').annotate(Count('id')).filter(id__count__gt=1)
query = Application.objects.filter(school_name__in=[item['school_name'] for item in dupes])
```

The *query* variable returns a queryset with the Applications that have duplicate values for the field *school_name* while this line:

```
repeated_names = Application.objects.values('school_name', 'category', ).annotate(Count('id')).order_by().filter(id__count__gt=1)
```

returns a list of the duplicated school names.

What I expect is something like:

(school_name=school_name_1, count=2), (school_name=school_name_2, count=3).. etc.

Comment: You obviously are rendering this data in front end right?

Comment: @ans2human yes, that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

In your `Views.py` use this queryset:

```
repeated_names = Application.objects.values('school_name', 'category').annotate(Count('id')).order_by().filter(id__count__gt=0)   # <--- gt 0 will get all the objects having occurred in DB i.e is greater than 0
```

> `gt 0` will get all the objects having occurred in DB i.e is greater than 0

In your `Template`:

```
 {% for c in repeated_names %}

 <ul>

 <li>{{c.school_name}}</li>

 <li>{{c.id__count}}</li>

 <li>{{c.category}}</li>


</ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked with the `client_` ommitted. But is there no way I way I can do this in the views?

Comment: And also, how can I get access to the values of other fields on the same row?

Comment: @Abedy Yes Updated the answer, You're already doing it in the views. To get rest of the fields data i have updated the query. Please check

Comment: The updated query seems to have a bug. It only displays one item.

Comment: @Abedy update the question with query you are using now and also the error you're getting. I'll check.

Comment: @Abedy What does the bug say?

Comment: No message, just that when I run my server, only one item, (the first item with duplicates) is displayed. The rest of the items are not.

Comment: Okay, so do you have only `ONE` object(`school_name`) in db with duplicates?

Comment: I have my model `Application` with the fields, `school_name` , `category` , among other fields. The `school_name` field can have duplicates. Currently I have 3 sets of duplicates, i.e object 1 and 2 have the same `school_name` , 3 and 4 another similar `school_name`. The Updated Query only gives me the school name for the first duplicate and the count. Doesn't account for the others

Comment: Now that works as I'd like it to, only that it displays a single entry at a time. Like, it doesn't add the number of duplicates to come up with a count for each duplicate. But I can work my way around that. Thanks big time @ans2human

Comment: @Abedy Welcome.