# Select rows with multiple duplicate field values

Tags: python, django

I want to select rows in Django which have multiple rows with duplicated values.

For example I have a model which looks like this

```py
class User:
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

and a database looking like this

```
first_name | last_name | ...
---------- | --------- | ...
Paul       | Adams     | ...
John       | Smith     | ...
Tom        | Mueller   | ...
John       | Smith     | ...
John       | Adams     | ...
Paul       | Adams     | ...
```

and I want to get the `first_name` and `last_name` values which exist multiple times in the database. The other values must not be equal of the rows. In this example I want to get "John Smith" and "Paul Adams".

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values) an answer to your question?

Comment: @Brambor No it isn't. I found this question already, but it only works if the value of one field is duplicated, not of multiple fields.

Comment: Can't you just use the answer twice to filter by two columns?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, maybe I did something wrong. I can try again later.

Comment: try doing something like `.values("first_field", "second_field")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in **views.py** or in your django shell using `py manage.py shell`

```
from django.db.models import Count
#import your User model 

users_output = User.objects.values('first_name','last_name').annotate(first_name_count=Count('first_name'),last_name_count = Count('last_name')).filter(first_name_count__gt=1,last_name_count__gt=1)
```

the above query will return a query set something like this

```
<QuerySet
 [{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'first_name_count': 2, 'last_name_count': 2},
 {'first_name': 'Paul', 'last_name': 'Adams', 'first_name_count': 2, 'last_name_count': 2}]
>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to concat fields.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset = User.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name', output_field=CharField())
```

then you need to group and calculate the count for each unique full_name

```
queryset = queryset.values('full_name').annotate(full_name_count=Count('full_name'))
```

and just filter those with count bigger than one.

```
queryset = queryset.filter(full_name_count__gt=1)
```