# query django model with same modelfields

Tags: django, django-models

so i have this django model

```
class terrain(models.Model):
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    size=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.location)
```

how do i get the location of diffrent terrains having the same size ,i used the filter but i have to specify the size for example

```
data=terrain.objects.filter(size="big")
```

can't i do this without specifying the size just by pasing the size field

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values/8989348) this is for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the field. but there are multiple way to filter you can do it on one field or multiple field depends on your requirement.

see documentation: [django_ filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 0):

```
terrains = terrain.objects.all()
data = {}

for terrain in terrains:
    if data.get(terrain.size, None):
        data[terrain.size] = []
    data[terrain.size].append(terrain.location)

print(data) # this will contain all of the locations for different terrain size..
```