# How to find duplicates of django model on two fields?

Tags: django, django-models

Consider this django model setup:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                 null=False,
                                 blank=False,
                                 unique=True,)

class Bar(models.Model):
    field_bar = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                 null=False,
                                 blank=False,
                                 unique=True,)

class Foobar(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.ForeignKey(foo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_bar = models.ForeignKey(bar,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to look for two rows that have the same `field_foo` and `field_bar` values. I can do this manually, but I want to know if there is a feature of django that takes care of that. The way I do this now is:

```
for f in Foo.objects.all():
    for b in Bar.objects.all():
        fb = Foobar.objects.filter(foo=f, bar=b)
        if len(fb)>2:
            something='do'
```

Comment: I havent tested (setting up those models can be time consuming),but  this  pure orm query should work, `Foobar.objects.filter(field_foo__field_foo=F('field_bar__field_bar')).values("field_foo__field_foo").annotate(freq=Count("field_foo__field_foo")).filter(freq__gte=2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [annotate(](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate)) and filter() methods together to filter the FooBar instances with the same Foo and Bar instances as relations.

Give this a try

```
duplicate_foobars = Foobar.objects.values('id', 'field_foo', 'field_bar').annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).filter(
    count__gt=1
).values_list('id', 'field_foo', 'field_bar')

for id, field_foo, field_bar in duplicate_foobars:
    print(f"Duplicate Foobar: #{id} field_foo={field_foo}, field_bar={field_bar}")
```

Output

```bash
Duplicate Foobar: #1, field_foo=1, field_bar=1
```

Tested models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )


class Bar(models.Model):
    field_bar = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )


class Foobar(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thanks. 

This is more or less what I need, but, is there a way for me to get the id of the duplicated ``Foobars``? I can do a query on the values, but is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: please try the updated anser

Answer (score 2):

Your manual way is also inefficient. You can do this in O(n) by using:

```
foo_bar_count = {}
for fb in Foobar.objects.all():
    foo_bar_pair = (fb.field_foo_id, fb.field_bar_id)
    
    if foo_bar_pair not in foo_bar_count:
        foo_bar_count[foo_bar_pair] = 0
        continue

    foo_bar_count[foo_bar_pair] += 1

    if foo_bar_count[foo_bar_pair] > 2:
        # do something
```

You can also try doing this using some fancy query. Check:
[Django select only rows with duplicate field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values)

Comment: Thanks, my concern was efficiency indeed. 

Just a question, doesn't storing things in a dictionary makes the search as inefficient as my approach. I mean, I now add storing and getting info from a dictionary.

Comment: In your approach you are doing 2 queries to database at first and then O(n*m) queries . So for 1000 (n) Foo and 1000 (m) bar you will make 1 000 002 queries to the database which will be extremely slow. In my case there is always only one query and operations on dict is very fast. The downside is memory usage.

Comment: How costly are they in memory terms (assuming the same numbers).

Comment: I ran some benchmark and it was saying that, in the worst case scenario of 1 000 000 FooBar objects with unique pairs it will take 100 MB of memory

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a typo in your question (there is a `f` instead of a `b`, what you want is an alternative to `fb = Foobar.objects.filter(foo=f, bar=b)` for any pair `f`,`b`), here's a hint:

```py
queryset = (
    Foobar.objects
    .values("field_foo", "field_bar")
    .annotate(nb=models.Count("id"))
    .filter(nb__gt=1)
)
```

Actually, the most optimal approach will depend on what you want to achieve then.

(1) If you want to know how many `Foobar` instances exist for each couple of values `f`,`b`:

```py
foobars = queryset.values("field_foo__field_foo", "field_bar__field_bar", "nb")
```

(2) Or if you want to retrieve all corresponding instances, you could do:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

any_of = (
    Q(field_foo__field_foo=x, field_bar__field_bar=y)
    for x, y in queryset.values_list("field_foo__field_foo", "field_bar__field_bar")
)
criteria = Q()
for q_obj in any_of:
    criteria |= q_obj

Foobar.objects.filter(criteria)
```

There might be a way to do the same thing using a subquery too, [have a look at the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).