# Django: Select objects that have a duplicate value when related to same secondary object

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to find objects with duplicate values for a specific field, but only if they are related to the same secondary object.

For example, with the following models:

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

How do I select all Entry objects that have the same headline IF they are published in the same Blog. So headlines shared between blogs should not be included. (Bonus: An extra filter that extracts only duplicate headlines with the same publication date, still within the same blog).

---

The closest solution I have is based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8989348/20488494

The first part, obtaining duplicate values, is successful:

```py
dupe_entries_vals = (
    Entry.objects
    .values('blog', 'headline', 'pub_date')
    .order_by()
    .annotate(count=Count('headline'))
    .filter(count__gt=1)
)
```

But then I can't use the second part because it loses related object filtering. The PKs are also lost due to taking values (necessarily, otherwise the duplicate filtering fails), so I can't use those either.

```py
# No longer restricted to related blog
dupe_entries = Entry.objects.filter(headline__in=[e['headline'] for e in dupe_entries_vals])

# KeyError (id not in `dupe_entries_vals`)
dupe_entries = Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=[e['id'] for e in dupe_entries_vals])
```

So is there a nice solution for this? Either Django native or a direct SQL query that can be used for most DB backends (if this can't be constructed with Django, please explain)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres, you should be able to do something like this:

```py
qs = Entry.objects.all()
qs = qs.values("date", "headline", "blog_id")  # fields for group_by
qs = qs.annotate(ids=ArrayAgg("pk"))  # build a list of id for each group
qs = qs.filter(ids__len__gt=1)  # keep group with duplicates
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like this works, but it would be nice to have a more robust or generic solution that doesn't rely on specific postgres functionality. Is there something in the Django QuerySet construction possibilities or the nature of my query that prevents this?

Comment: You can easily remove the need for Postgres changing the aggregation function by a Count and using the grouping fileds as filters

Comment: How do I avoid losing the pk values in that case? I can't include them in the grouping because that makes them all unique and the count annotation no longer works.

Comment: You'll inevitably lose the ids. But you have the values of each grouping fields to use as filters `Entry.objects.filter(date=obj.date, headline=obj.headline, blog_id=obj.blog_id)`. Want do you intend of doing with your duplicates ?

Comment: What is `obj` in your filter? My first query provides me with a QuerySet of the dicts with the values specified and an additional count entry. I intend to delete the duplicates (after checking some other information).